# The Workplace activity missing from Network Profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, recent-activity, network-profile, specific-site

I just visited my own profile on stackexchange.com and noticed that the [activity tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/48256/nickc?tab=activity) is missing all activity from [The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com), while it seems to be a complete aggregation of the rest of my activity:

[image: Network activity]

You can see comments, badges, etc. from many other sites, and **no** activity from The Workplace.  All of the following [activity from The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/17/nickc?tab=activity) is missing:

[image: Workplace activity]

I clicked through all 5 pages, and couldn't see any Workplace activity.

The same seems to be true of other users, such as moderator [jmort253](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/98/jmort253?tab=activity) ([network activity](https://stackexchange.com/users/265671/jmort253?tab=activity)).

Is this intentional for some reason, or a bug?

Comment: True for me too.  However, Workplace *does* show up in my reputation graph, so whatever's affecting the site's visibility in the network profile doesn't affect *everything*.

Comment: Wow, a Taxonomist silver badage.

Comment: This is also happening on the new Meta Stack Exchange, for some reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, Meta.SE, Workplace.SE, and Money.SE were incorrectly filtered from that list because of a data inconsistency. Fixed now.

Comment: Meta.ServerFault is also filtered? [Here's 2 activities on my Meta.SF that should've shown up in my network profile](http://i.imgur.com/SEndtqM.png)